# Rails 3.2.11 suddenly needs a restart to 'acknowledge' any change in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Title says it all.

Note that this is **not** about a change in the model or initializers. 
I can delete an instance variable in the controller (say, @user) and then reload a view and it will work - until I restart the server, in which case it will complain about the variable being nil.

I was working normally and then switched to work on a totally different set of controllers and views and now it's happening for no reason whatsoever.

The app is in a development environment.

development.rb contents:

```
Dashboard::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

How can I find out how it's happening and how do I fix it?

**Edit:**
**It's likely related, but I can't seem to use any paths that exist when running 'rake routes' in a partial, such as dashboards_path**

**Plot twist:** 
Adding

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```

to development.rb seemed to have ameliorated the issue. I still would like to know why it happened, why it happened out of the blue and why it happened to one controller but not the other.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is using WEBrick?

Comment: I'm running Thin at the moment.

Comment: Just tested it out - switching to WEBrick didn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you using the `active_reload` gem, perchance? Did you recently add any new gems before you noticed this issue?

Comment: I'm not using active_reload and no - I was working on another controller(s) for the past day or so and it's only now it changed, quite puzzling

Comment: I can only assume that the issue dissapears after rolling back to a previous version, right? Maybe you can use a tool like git bisect to see when the problem started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses the autoload paths config to determine what files to auto load, and reload:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/lib/**/ #{config.root}/app/traits )

    ...

  end
end
```

As you can see I have added a custom directory, the app/traits directory, where I store some modules that define shared behavior.

If the controller you started working on is in a subdirectory that is not watched by rails or has permissions that stop rails from attaching a file system changed event you get this problem.

The reason that `config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false` "solves" the problem is that the entire app is reloaded on every request instead of relying on detecting changes to files.

Most likely the controller is not in the watched files list and thats why rails is not reloading it on change. The exact reason why it's not on the list might vary and I need more details about the folder structure and config of the app before I can give a good answer there...

Comment: That sounds about right. At the time it happened as it turned out I was having some issues with my raid0 hdd setup. I bet you that had something to do with it as unlikely as it sounds. Maybe lost permission to the folder, or something.